# serial port c programming receive data

Tags: c

Iam working simple c program to receive data from a sensor which sends data through UART. Working in Ubuntu. the program is as simple as shown below:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define BAUDRATE B9600   // Change as needed, keep B
#define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyS0" 
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

main()
{
    int fd, c, res;
    char buf[1024];
    struct termios oldtio, newtio;

    fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd < 0) 
    { 
    perror(MODEMDEVICE); 
    exit(-1); 
    }

    bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio)); /* clear struct for new port settings */


    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;


    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;

    /*  Raw output  */
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;


    newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;
    /* now clean the modem line and activate the settings for the port */
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);

    while (TRUE) {     /* loop continuously */

        memset(buf,0,1024);

        res = read(fd, buf, 1024);
        buf[res] = 0;             /* set end of string, so we can printf */
        printf("%s\n", buf);

    }
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio);
}
```

this program is working but, it receives some data like:

```
abcdef,234.456,678.234,w,e,123.5566,78.90,12344.567,3456.789
abcdef,234.456,678.234,w,e,123.5566,78.90,12344.567,3456.789
abcdef,234.456,678.234,w,e,123.5566,78.90,12344.567,3456.789
abcdef,234.456,678.234,w,e,123.5566,78.90,12344.567,3456.789
abcdef,234.456,678.234,w,e,123.5566,78.90,12344.567,3456.789
abcdef,234.456,678.234,w,e,123.5566,78.90,12344.567,3456.789
abcdef,234.456,678.234,w,e,123.5566,78.90,12344.567,3456.789
```

after continuing while loop for 5-8 times, then it is not receiving data. program doesn't exit(it will in running state only) , but data it will not print.

How to make this program to receive the data continuously...(for infinite number of times)

Comment: where's buf defined?

Comment: This isn't real code. I can tell because you posted it missing a variable declaration, and when someone noticed you threw one in really quickly. Post your **actual code**. Also, if it's stopping after *5-8 times*, use a debugger and step through the code to find out what happens on 6-9th time.

Comment: Agreed.  Post code that actually compiles and is truly representative of the issue.    But....do you need to assert any flow control signals or XON to the modem?

Comment: do you expect the program to exit? Sounds like it's blocking on `read` to me.. sure your sensor is generating data the whole time? Should also check if `read` returns -1

Comment: `char buf[1024]; ... res = read(fd, buf, 1024);
        buf[res] = 0;` --> `read(fd, buf, 1024-1);`

Comment: there are two valid signatures for the `main()` function: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  the missing return type of `int` in the posted code causes the compiler (except visual studio) to output a warning.  Warnings should be fixed, not ignored

Comment: note: the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: the posted code is including a lot of header files that are not being used in the code.  Strongly suggest removing the `#include` statements for header files those contents are not used

Comment: there is the variable `c` declared, but not used.  Strongly suggest removing that variable

Comment: the `TRUE` and `FALSE` are properly defined in the header file: `stdbool.h`  Suggest using that header file rather than defining your own

Comment: the code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 1024  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: the variable `oldtio` was never set (via a call to `tcgetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio);`  so the call at the program of `tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio); is completely corrupting the serial interface, not restoring it to its' original (power up) value

Comment: within the `while()` loop two LONG execution calls are being made: the call to `memset()` and the call to `printf()`.   First the call to `memset()` is completely unneeded.  Strongly suggest to (at least) double buffer the input.  A MUCH FASTER call would be `puts( buf );`

Comment: when calling `read()`, always check that the returned value is >= 0 and if <0 then handle the error.

Comment: this line: `res = read(fd, buf, 1024);` is trying to read one too many bytes. being successful would leave no room for the line: `buf[res] = 0;`  Suggest: `res = read(fd, buf, 1023);` Note: regarding this line: `buf[res[ = 0;` 'implicit conversion' feature would save you, but 0 is an integer and takes sizeof(int) bytes. Suggest: `buf[res] = '\0';

Comment: I didn't asked for the comments on the program given... i already told the program is working fine... while copying the program (since i copied part by part.. i missed char buf[1024]... that should be unstood by evry7 programmer that if char buf[1024] is not defined.. program will not work... i already is stated that it is working but able to receive limited data.. none of the above comments could able to give me a valid solution like why it is receiving limited data only...

Comment: It can be caused by error in reading also. I would recommend checking value of `res`, if this value is `-1`, then some error occurred while reading UART channel. This might show what the problem is.